# How to run Dapp on the Fantom blockchain?

Tags: solidity, web3js, rinkeby, fantom

I have deployed 2 contracts on Fantom that were running on Rinkeby. Worked really well. However, when I run my Dapp using "yarn dev", I get nothing. It cannot connect to the blockchain.

So my question is do I need to do anything special? Is it the localhost port that I need to change to be 8545 or something else instead of 3000?

Here is the code where I connect to MetaMask:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {

    window.ethereum.enable();

    // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
        web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the user doesn't have Metamask installed
        // Probably show them a message prompting them to install Metamask
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3js = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:3000");

    }

    web3js.eth.defaultAccount = web3js.eth.accounts[0];

    // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
    startApp()
  })
```

I appreciate any help you can give me...

Thank-you!

Comment: We do need more information and code? how did you connect to rinkeby previously with your DAPP?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue my using the following code to set the provider:

```
web3js = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://rpc.fantom.network/");
```

The complete code snippet now looks like this:

```
   window.addEventListener('load', function() {
   
   window.ethereum.enable();

    // Checking if Web3 has been injected by the browser (Mist/MetaMask)
    if (typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
        // Use Mist/MetaMask's provider
        web3js = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);
    } else {
        // Handle the case where the user doesn't have Metamask installed
        // Probably show them a message prompting them to install Metamask
        // set the provider you want from Web3.providers
        web3js = new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://rpc.fantom.network/");

    }

    web3js.eth.defaultAccount = web3js.eth.accounts[0];

    // Now you can start your app & access web3 freely:
    startApp()
  })
```